# Security Trimming ActionLink or Anchor Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Is there inbuilt support for security trimming action links or tag helpers in MVC6? Or do we have to build this ourselves? If so anyone done something similar or do I have to reimplement my MVC5 code?

I would hope to be able to optionally hide a generated link if I can't gain access to it based on my access to the action

Comment: If the user does not have access to the link, you should simply not execute the code to render the link!

Comment: So we are writing conditional code around thousands of links?